# Magento - checkout 404 not found error

Tags: magento

I have followed this tutorial : 
http://www.igorkrasnykh.com/2010/04/14/bypass-magento-payment-and-shipping-1-4/comment-page-1/#comment-319

to bypass the Payment and Shipping Methods im Magento, but this create a 404 error when  click on Checkout link (in the toplinks).

How can correct this error ??

Please help !

Comment: What version of Magento? Are you sure you are requiring the existing Mage Controller on line one of the local OnepageController?  `require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';`

Comment: I use Magento version 1.4.1.1

The require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';
works 

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always flush the caches after install new extension or sources, this will kill lots of 404 problems.

Then post logs here will be helpful to understand your problem. thanks.